# Docker, varnish, Connection reset by peer

Tags: php, nginx, docker, varnish

I'm just trying to set up a web server using Docker.
I have 3 different containers:

- jprjr/php-fpm

  `sudo docker run --name c_php-fpm -v $HOME/data/webstack/www:/srv/http:ro -p 9000:9000 -d jprjr/php-fpm`
- nginx

  `sudo docker run --name c_nginx -v $HOME/data/webstack/www:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -p 8080:80 --link c_php-fpm:c_php-fpm -d nginx nginx`
- jacksoncage/varnish

  `sudo docker run --name c_varnish -i -d -p 80:80 --link c_nginx:c_nginx -e VARNISH_BACKEND_PORT=80 -e VARNISH_BACKEND_IP=c_nginx jacksoncage/varnish`

PHP and nginx are working without any problem but there is an error for varnish:

`curl -I http://localhost/index.html
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

`sudo docker ps` return:

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                           NAMES
4ee21c4a80e2        jacksoncage/varnish:latest   "/bin/bash"         25 minutes ago      Up 25 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp              c_varnish

4dcc7babd92c        nginx:latest                 "nginx"             16 hours ago        Up 48 minutes       443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   c_nginx

3c0f8c1d634c        jprjr/php-fpm:latest         "php-fpm -F"        16 hours ago        Up 48 minutes       0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp          c_php-fpm`

`sudo docker logs c_varnish` return nothing.

Thanks !

Comment: I also got "Connection reset by peer" on a different app because my server (running inside container) was listening only on localhost. Can you get into the Varnish container via `docker exec -it varnish bash` and try `curl -I http://localhost/index.html` inside?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have the following error: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused`.

Comment: This means that Varnish is not really listening on port 80 inside the container. Try starting `./start.sh` manually and check for errors. BTW my previous command should have said `docker exec -it c_varnish bash` (not `varnish`).

Comment: It's return: `Backend host '"${VARNISH_BACKEND_IP}"' could not be resolved to an IP address:
 Servname not supported for ai_socktype
(Sorry if that error message is gibberish.)
('input' Line 8 Pos 13)
    .host = "${VARNISH_BACKEND_IP}";
------------#######################-


In backend specification starting at:
('input' Line 7 Pos 1)
backend default {
#######----------

Running VCC-compiler failed, exit 1

VCL compilation failed
Cannot open /var/lib/varnish/4ee21c4a80e2/_.vsm: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the current image of the container related with Varnish VCL files no longer accepting environment variables in the backend config: https://github.com/jacksoncage/varnish-docker/issues/2

To solve it, get the original Dockerfile and associated files from https://github.com/jacksoncage/varnish-docker, apply the patch in https://github.com/jacksoncage/varnish-docker/pull/3/commits and rebuild the image with

```
sudo docker build -t jacksoncage/varnish .
```

You should be able to run new containers with the generated image working correctly.

Comment: Thanks @dukebody, the patch is now committed into master and a new version not using environment variables inside varnish config is now available on docker hub, please pull down via `docker pull jacksoncage/varnish`